# Make a divs background image repeat a source file inside of it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm wondering if there's a way with perhaps, jQuery, to take an image and repeat it into the background of a div. For example, you have a few rotating pictures in a div such as:

```
<div id="slides">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/1024x200">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/1024x200">
</div>
```

So those img files would then repeat into the background of their parent div (i.e. #slides) as they rotate. I know this probably seems redundant, but it's to apply a quick fix to a problem I have instead of recoding the entire website.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to repeat a background with ONE image is with css.

```
div#slides{
  image:url('http://placehold.it/1024x200')
  background-repeat:repeat-y
}
```

But it sounds like you want something more like a slideshow. There are a few jQuery plugins that do this and that's probably your best beat.

The basic raw code is something like this. I didn't test it, but you should get the idea.

```
function ghettoSlideShow() {
    $("div#slides", "img").hide(); //Hide all the images
    $("div#slides", "img").each(i) {
      $(this).fadeIn(slow); //Foreach image show it
    }
    ghettoSlideShow(); //Do it again
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a class or id tag to signify the image or do inline css

The first method you would need to label the images in some way

then in your css `background-repeat:repeat;`

Or the second method apply inline stying

`<img src="placehold.it/1024x1024" style="background-repeat:repeat;">`

If you are looking for a javascript version you would also need to label the image with a class or id to reference it

Then you could type

```
$(".image-class").style("background-repeat","repeat")
```

To also make it so they only fit into their bounding box by messing with overflow or width and height